# MySQL Error #1442. How to avoid it

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a hieralchical structure of families, marking the leaf nodes. I have a `Trigger` to mark the `family` as a leaf but when I try to save a record the following error happens:

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'family' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

My trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MARK_LEAF BEFORE INSERT ON FAMILY FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE V_IS_LEAF  CHAR(1);

    SELECT IS_LEAF INTO V_IS_LEAF FROM FAMILY WHERE ID = NEW.PARENT_ID;

    IF (V_IS_LEAF = 'F') THEN
        UPDATE FAMILY SET IS_LEAF = 'T' WHERE ID = NEW.PARENT_ID;
    END IF;
END
```

**Note:**  `family` fields are `ID, PARENT_ID, IS_LEAF`

**Note 2:** Notice that I always update the `parent_id` and my structure is hieralchical so there isn't a loop. Besides, I check if the value is `'F'` and I try to change it  to `'T'`, so, if I made a mistake with the parent it only update the same row once.

Is there any way to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution because this is a restriction of MySQL. In the **[documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)** they say this is one of their restrictions is :

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already
>   being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>   function or trigger.

So, I'm afraid that the solution is to put the mark by updating the rows in my programming language